# Dynamically create generic type of an Expression.Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to create lambda expressions, type:

```
Expression.Lambda <Func<T,TProperty>>
```

but without knowing the TProperty, to save them in a collection.

```
public BuilderMapping<T> AutoMap()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyInfo.Name);

        // propertyInfo.PropertyType == TProperty
        //  I have not TProperty
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(body, param);

        var prop = new PropertyDescriptor<T, TProperty>
        {
            Selector = exp
        };
        _descriptorColumn.Add(prop);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You can use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` or the ungeneric `Expression.Lambda`. But I wonder how you would use those delegates if you don´t know their return-types.

Comment: Which `PropertyDescriptor` class are you referring to? It can't be the one from `System.ComponentModel`, since it's not generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), propertyInfo.PropertyType);
var exp = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, param);
```

`PropertyDescriptor<T, TProperty>` will need similar treatment, I think the shortest way would be this:

```
dynamic prop = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PropertyDescriptor<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), propertyInfo.PropertyType));
prop.Selector = (dynamic)exp;
```